# Creating a feed (following) grouped by day and user that is ordered by most recent on ruby on rails

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, feed

I am trying to do a feed (kinda timeline following feed in a daily manner)

I have a table `photos` where it stores photos uploaded by the user, a table `follows` which stores the user that each user is following.

```
 create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
 ...
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
 ...

create_table "follows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "followable_id",                   null: false
    t.string   "followable_type",                 null: false
    t.integer  "follower_id",                     null: false
    t.string   "follower_type",                   null: false
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Basically, I want to accomplish a feed that looks like this (easier drawn than explain)

[image]

- most recent appear at the top
- group all photos uploaded by the user we are "following" including my own in "a day"
- display today, yesterday, 2 days ago and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is one solution.

```
current_user_id = current_user.id

Photo.select(%q{
  user_id, 
  COUNT(*) no_photos, 
  date_trunc('day', created_at::timestamp) as what_day
}).group("what_day, user_id").order("what_day DESC").where(%Q{
  user_id IN (
    (SELECT followable_id FROM follows where follower_id = #{current_user_id})
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT #{current_user_id} as followable_id)
  )
})
```

`date_trunc` truncates the date to a specified precision, in this case the beginning of a day. I'm not sure what `follows.followable_type` does in your case, but the above should work.

Comment: followable_type = the act as followable gem
allows any entities to follow any entities. So id by itself is insufficient
need combination of entity type i.e. followable_type and id

Comment: thanks for your answer, we will try it out, but im just wondering whether it also includes "your own user id - your own feed" ? i feel thats missing. thanks

Comment: @Axil It includes everyone you're following. Should it also include the owners action?

Comment: @ Oleander yes how do i include "also" the "owner" (meaning the current_user_id). Thanks. My dev is looking to this to verify your work. Will let you know.

Comment: @ oleander, thanks i'll update this once its tested. Thanks again!